# Set mutiple values in one parameter

Tags: powershell

I have written the following script to compare jobs that I have saved in a folder and compare them by name on the servers.

```
$submaporiginal = 'D:\Jobs_from_Server\TEST_Jobs_Aangepast'

$SqlServer1Name = "servername"

$SqlServer1 = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server($SqlServer1Name)

$files = Get-ChildItem $submaporiginal *.sql 

$SqlServer1JobListing = $SqlServer1.JobServer.Jobs | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

foreach ($file in $files) 
    {
    $stap1 =  $file.Name  
    $locatiedtsx = $stap1.IndexOf("_goed")
    $SqlServer2JobListing = $stap1.Substring(0,$locatiedtsx)
    }

Compare-Object $SqlServer1JobListing $SqlServer2JobListing 
    {
    if ($_.SideIndicator -eq "<=") 
        {Write-Host $_}
    }
```

After running it shows a list with all the jobs that are currently on the server but are not saved in the folder: TEST_Jobs_Aangepast

My problem is that currently it only ignores the last job that have run trough the `foreach ($file in $files)`

For excample in the map are the files TestA.sql and TestB.SQL while the server has a job named testA, TestB and TestC. 
The result shown should be:

- TestC <=

but the actual result is shows:

- TestA <=
- TestC <=

My question is how can I set all the values that go trough `foreach ($file in $files)` in one parameter `SqlServer2JobListing` so that all the jobs that match between `$SqlServer1JobListing $SqlServer2JobListing`  are not shown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you always reassign the `$SqlServer2JobListing` variable, instead you need to add a value to array or list. Like this:

```
$SqlServer1JobListing = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
foreach ($file in $files) 
{
    $stap1 =  $file.Name  
    $locatiedtsx = $stap1.IndexOf("_goed")
    $SqlServer1JobListing.Add($stap1.Substring(0,$locatiedtsx))
}
```

This way, after your `foreach` loop you will get a collection of all the items, rather than only the last one like you had before.

Comment: Hi the code works pretty good but is shows a list wit the matches not a list with packages that do not match.